# Disable panning after loading a layer in ArcGIS Runtime

Tags: .net, android, basemap, arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-.net

I have a MapView, I am loading a base map, and then I am loading a layer. Then I am setting the View Point to be that of the extent of the layer. The map loads and is zoomed to the extent of the Layer. Is it possible to stop the user from leaving the extent of the map that was set? Basically I do not want the user to pan outside of the extent. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: Are you asking to completely disable panning and/or navigation, or just prevent panning/zooming outside that area?

Comment: Basically to prevent panning and/or navigation. they can zoom in zoom out to that fixed location, but no panning or navigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mapView.InteractionOptions = new Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.MapViewInteractionOptions()
{
    IsPanEnabled = false
};
```